# Document click fire after control click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a common click function in jquery which fires every time when clicked any where on document. If  control has click event then that event fires first and document click fires after that but i want to fire document click event before control click event. please suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Two options for you:

1. You can do that on modern browsers by using the *capturing* phase of an event rather than the bubbling phase. This diagram from [the DOM events specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) helps with understanding the various phases of an event:

   [image]

   IE doesn't support event capture until IE9 in standards mode (IE8 and earlier simply do not have it).

   jQuery doesn't provide an API for using event capture, so you'd have to use `addEventListener` instead:

   ```
   document.querySelector("selector for the control").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       // Control code here
   }, true);
   document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       // Document code here
   }, true);
   ```

   The `true` at the end means you want to use the capturing phase, rather than the bubbling phase.
2. Don't handle clicks on controls directly, use event delegation, handling clicks on the document and, if the click came through a control, calling your control-specific handling from the document click handler:

   ```
   $(document).on("click", handleDocumentClick);

   function handleDocumentClick(e) {
     // On the next line, use whatever selector matches your controls
     var input = $(e.target).closest("input")[0];
     display("document click received");
     if (input) {
       handleControlClick.call(input, e);
     }
   }

   function handleControlClick(e) {
     display("control click received");
   }
   ```

   [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/rohaq/1)

Comment: what is meant by ``"use strict";``??

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for the reply. I  have completed all the application and i just want to apply some functionality and its not possible to change all click events so please suggest me the better way for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Supreet: I don't think there is one. If you said *what* you're trying to apply, we might be able to, but if you've hooked up all of your event handlers the normal way, there's no quick and easy way to get a document-level click event prior to the element-level click event.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: `"use strict";` tells an ES5-enabled JavaScript engine to enable the strict variant of JavaScript ("strict mode"). Strict mode is a Good Thing(tm). It protects you from [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), for one thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `live()`. `live()` binds the click event to the DOM's document element. As browser events bubble up through the DOM tree, the click event is triggered for any matching elements.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    alert('document');    
});
$(document).live('click', 'div', function() {
   alert('div'); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3d021kuh/)

Comment: Except, of course, `live` was deprecated three years ago (v1.7) and removed a year and a half ago (v1.9), and the replacement, `on`, doesn't have the same behavior (the order is different).